# Arranging output to CSV from Powershell foreach loop

Tags: csv, powershell, foreach

I am writing a powershell function which executes a foreach loop. The loops goes through each server name in a text file list of hosts and then for each one, pulls the free space on C and then assigns it to a variable.

Then another loop goes through the list again and gets the name of the hosts and then adds it to a variable.

Then I have a variable which takes the two variables containing the data pulled from the loops and export it to CSV. It puts the correct data in the CSV but I would like to format it in a certain way. The current csv output is (for 4 entries for example) 'server 1' 'server2' 'server 3' 'server 4' 'diskspacevalue1' '2' '3' '4' etc.

So Im at the point where I have all the data I need but I need to arrange it so that one cell has the server name and then the cell next to it has it's respective value.

I have a feeling I should be creating objects or using an array but wondered if there was anything I could add to implement the formatting I want based on the script I have written so far?

```
function diskcheck {
    $freespace = Get-Content C:\temp2\DiskspaceProj\hosts.txt | Foreach-Object {
        Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Computername $_ -Filter "DeviceID='C:'" | select -ExpandProperty "FreeSpace"
    }
    $hostName = Get-Content C:\temp2\DiskspaceProj\hosts.txt | Foreach-Object {
        Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $_ | Select -ExpandProperty "Name"
    }
    $output = "$hostname, $freespace" | echo > C:\temp2\DiskspaceProj\diskspace.csv
}
diskcheck
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't maintain two separate array - create *one* array of objects that contain both properties:

```
function diskcheck 
{
    param(
        [string]$Path = 'C:\temp2\DiskspaceProj\hosts.txt'
    )

    Get-Content $Path |ForEach-Object {
        New-Object psobject -Property @{
            Hostname = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $_ |Select -ExpandProperty Name
            FreeSpace = Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Computername $_ -Filter "DeviceID='C:'" | select -ExpandProperty FreeSpace
        }
    }
}
```

Then use `Export-CSV` to export the list to a file:

```
diskcheck |Select Hostname,FreeSpace |Export-Csv C:\diskspace_output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: That runs great. However I am getting a strange output in the CSV. The values show as 'System.Object[]' in each cell. Any ideas?